# How to call threads before other threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to threading and don't quite understand the structuring of it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Gone()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Gone");
        }
    }

    static void Going()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {       
            Console.WriteLine("Going");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to alter the above code so that the main thread creates a thread calling the Gone method. Also, I want to alter the Gone method so it creates a thread to hit Going *before* it prints gone. I'm assuming a Join would be used in the latter of my problem but I don't know where to put threads or where to use a join ( I had the following code within the Main method but that only displayed the word "Gone" 5 times and not "Going".

```
Thread t = new Thread(Gone);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
```

Comment: I advise against using the `Thread` class if possible for short lived threading. Use the ThreadPool instead, or better yet, use TPL. But fact is in many cases, when someone asks about threading in C# they actually want asynchronicity, in which case you want to use `async` `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly but this is what I would do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Gone));

        thread2.Start();

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Gone()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {


            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Going));
            thread1.Start();
            thread1.Join();
            Console.WriteLine("Gone");
        }
    }
    static void Going()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {       
            Console.WriteLine("Going");
        }
    }
```

Output:

`Going
Going
Gone
Going
Going
Gone
Going
Going
Gone
Going
Going
Gone
Going
Going
Gone`

This will run synchronously.

Comment: Ah yes this is what I wanted to see and you used threading like I asked. Thank you very much, I can use this setup in another program where I need to add some threading. How would I add a thread.sleep method somewhere? It says there is no definition for sleep in visual studio :/

Comment: @Shiro - Just keep in mind that using threads is like juggling knives. Just because you've been shown once how to do it it doesn't mean you won't cut yourself badly when you try it yourself. In about 99.9% of situations you really should use `await`, Tasks, or Rx, or some other high-level abstraction, before you even think about creating your own threads.

Comment: @Shiro The sleep method is a static method located in Thread class. You can find more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: oh and this was just for an example program, I won't be using threading for much else and will rather think of using await instead. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Typed but not compiled.. I think you want this -- you'll need to tweak a bit if it doesn't build/run, but it gives the general idea:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
        Console.Read();
    }

    static async void Run()
    {
         await Gone();
    }

    static async void Gone()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            await Going();
            Console.WriteLine("Gone");
        }
    }

    static async void Going()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {       
            Console.WriteLine("Going");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Aron - You're quite right. Just tested the code in LinqPad and it all does run on the one thread.